# Create One Calendar Event for Recordset range

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, office-automation

I'm trying to figure out how to add a loop that will only create one Outlook calendar event per Markdown End Date.

In my Table Pack Number 6772457 has a shared Markdown End Date date between all my Brand Offers of 2/9/2022 8AM. I'd like to find a way to create only one Entry for all these Brand Offers.

Logically, I'm having an issue figuring out how I would do a loop that would see Multiple Pack numbers on different dates and create event.

Note: The recordset could have multiple pack numbers with different dates and I want to try to make it so each pack number with a date gets a calendar event.
My current code is below.

Any thoughts or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

| Pack_Number | Brand Offer | Markdown End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6772457 | W6 | 2/9/2022 8:00:00 AM |
| 6772457 | V6 | 2/9/2022 8:00:00 AM |
| 6772457 | S6 | 2/9/2022 8:00:00 AM |
| 6772457 | R6 | 2/9/2022 8:00:00 AM |
| 6772457 | P6 | 2/9/2022 8:00:00 AM |

```
Private Sub Process_InSeason_Click()
Dim olobj As Outlook.Application
Dim oloappt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim myOptionalAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
Dim PackNum As String
Dim rs As Dao.Recordset

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Define objects
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Appt = [Forms]![In Season MD Tracking]![InS_tbl_Original].[Form]![Markdown End Date].Value
Appt = DateSerial(Year(Appt), Month(Appt), Day(Appt))
Appt = Appt + TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)

PackNum = [Forms]![In Season MD Tracking]![InS_tbl_Original].[Form]![Pack_Number].Value

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("InS_tbl_Original")
Set olobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oloappt = olobj.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
Set myOptionalAttendee = oloappt.Recipients.Add("")
myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Save records and turn on Error Control
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
On Error GoTo Add_Err

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Validate if Markdown End date is future date
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If rs.Fields("Markdown End Date").Value > Date Then

With oloappt
        .RequiredAttendees = myOptionalAttendee
        .Subject = "InSeason TEST" 'PackNum & " TEST"
        '.Body =
        .MeetingStatus = 1
        .ResponseRequested = True
        .Start = Appt
        .Duration = 10
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 1440
        .Save
        '.Display
        .Send
        .Close (olSave)
End With
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
MsgBox "Appointment Added!"

Else 'do nothing
End If

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'End process and clean up
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set oloappt = Nothing
Set olobj = Nothing

Exit Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Error validation
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Add_Err:
MsgBox "oops error found " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In order to make this work I created a query off my table that will remove duplicate pack Numbers. From there I created a look through the records of the query. I want to leave this code active though for anyone who is trying to setup an outlook event through Access. Hopefully this helps!